# How does one justifies rigorously the passage to the limit inside the bounds of the set in the indicator function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, measure-theory

To apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, in

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{|f(t)|>1/n\}}|f(t)| dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 |f(t)| 1_{\{|f(t)|> 1/n\}}  dt $$

I need  to show:

$|1_{\{|f(t)|> 1/n\}} |f(t)| | \le |f(t)|$

and

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(t)| 1_{\{|f(t)|> 1/n\}}   =  |f(t)|  $ ...(1)

**The first one is clear. Regarding (1), it is intuitively clear, but I want to be precise, it looks as though, entering into the set's bounds with the limit were some property I should know:**

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(t)| 1_{\{|f(t)|> 1/n\}}   = |f(t)| 1_{\{|f(t)|> \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n\}} $ ...(2)

or if I write $1_{\{|f(t)|> 1/n\}} = 1_{(1/n,\infty)}(|f(t)|)$

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(t)| 1_{(1/n,\infty)}(|f(t)|)  = |f(t)| 1_{( \lim_{n \to \infty} 
 1/n,\infty)}(|f(t)|) =  |f(t)| 1_{(0,\infty)}(|f(t)|)  $ ...(3)

**Are (2) and (3) informal ways of taking the limits? How does one justifies them rigorously?**

Comment: $\lim f \mathbf{1}_{f > 1/n} = f \mathbf{1}_{f > 0}.$ (If $x > 0$ then $x > 1/n$ for all $n$ large enough.)

Comment: The convergence in the second equation needs to hold pointwise, not necessarily uniformly, in the hypotheses of LDCT. For any fixed $t$, it's clear that $|f(t)| > 1/n$ for sufficiently large $n$ if $f(t) \not = 0$; and if $f(t) = 0$, then the result holds trivially.

Comment: @anomaly, can't this arguments be formalized? they look informal, as a way to avoid some long calculation. Is it  coorect in (2) and (3) to write the limit inside the indicator? I haven't seen any property dealing with that , I mean we have theorems for the limit of a sum, of a product, of a composition, etc, but not for this

Comment: What's informal about it? If you want to match the (or at least a) usual definition of the limit, take $n > 1/f(t)$.